# Ubuntu 14.04 super slow after install

Tags: system-installation

I have a Compaq with Intel Atom CPU D410 @ 1.66 Ghz x2, RAM is 2 Gb and Intel IGDx86/MMX/SSE2.

When I boot Ubuntu from the live CD it worked like a charm even in my old computer, so I decided to install it as a dual boot with Windows 7. After the installation it was terribly slow. I have already try re-installing it but nothing changed.

Is it that my computer is just too old to run Ubuntu? If so, then why did it work perfectly fine from the liveCD? Thanks for your help.

The result of the command `sudo fdisk -l` is this

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc4478cd1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   840583167   420188160    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       953223168   976771071    11773952    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       840583168   953223167    56320000    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       840585216   861065215    10240000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       861067264   871307263     5120000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       871309312   932749311    30720000   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Comment: you could perhaps add in your question the result of the command `sudo fdisk -l` to have an idea how you set your partitions

Comment: I just added that informtaion.

Comment: Check your video. If you're not using the GPU for graphics, the load on the CPU will be very high. I'd expect a warning when you booted up about being in some "compatibility mode".

Answer (score 0):

I would check my hard disc. It probably does not have to do with your processor (because LiveCD worked perfectly).

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am sorry, I am really new to this.

Comment: its ok to be new... we all once were :D... but does your windows partition work well... or is it just ubuntu?

Comment: Windows works fine. Ubuntu is the OS that is running slow in  my computer.